# CSOM - find if content of library has changed

Tags: csom, library

I would like to check within client application (CSOM), if there have been any changes to any files in library in eg. last 15 minutes.

I know that there is `list.GetChanges` method in server-side object model, but it does not exist in CSOM. Is there another way to see if any file has changed, without having to go trough all the listitems first?

Comment: If you only want to know IF **anything** changed, can [LastItemModifiedDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) be of help?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danny Engelman gave correct answer in his comment:

`List` has [`LastItemModifiedDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) property, that will give time of last change to anything (list item, field, property) in the list.

Answer (score 2):

`List.GetChanges` method is also available in **CSOM**. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getchanges(v=office.15).aspx) is the *MSDN* pointer. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn986828.aspx) is some sample code.

> Returns the collection of changes from the change log that have
>   occurred within the list, based on the specified query.

## Syntax of C#

```
public ChangeCollection GetChanges(
    ChangeQuery query
)
```